# Why compact width and compact height in iPhone 4,5,6 in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, size-classes, adaptive-user-interfaces

I am new in iOS development and just studying Adaptivity and Layout I am stuck with a little confusion,

**As per the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)**

iOS defines two size classes:

1. Regular :- *It is associated with expansive space*
2. Compact :- *It is associated with constrained space*

**By other references :**

1. All iPhones (top left) in the portrait orientation have a regular height and a compact width like
   [image: Iphone in portrait]
2. Iphone 4, 5 and 6 in landscape orientation have compact height and compact width.
   [image: iphones in landscape orientation]
3. But in case of iPhone 6 Plus, It has compact height and a regular width in landscape orientation.

[image: Iphone 6 plush in landscape]

**My Confusion is :**

- iPhone 4,5,6 have regular height and compact width in portrait mode but Why they don't have regular width and compact height in landscape orientation as it was reversed?
- If so then why iPhone 6 plus is differ from them ? Is it because it's screen is 0.8" bigger then iPhone 6 ? Does it matter ?

**Thanks in advance!, Warm welcome to editors!**

*I know it won't affect in development so far technically But I just want to make my mind clear of these things.*

Comment: I think the key here is fact that plus models have landscape mode in general UI

Comment: If you are wondering why the "Regular Height" of the smaller iPhones in portrait orientation does _not_ translate to "Regular Width" when they are rotated to landscape, well... I guess Apple's expectations on What constitutes "Regular Width" are higher than for regular height. That's all I can think of. A bit  arbitrary, if you ask me.

Comment: @sage444 I think maybe it's the other way around: _because_ the 6+ has a **regular** (not compact) width in landscape orientation (due to it's screen size), it is allowed to display the landscape home screen (much like an iPad).

Comment: You'll never really get a satisfying answer to these sorts of questions. The answer to why it's done this way is that it's a human-made system and some human decided to do it that way.

Comment: I agree the 6 should have probably been regular width. You have to pay extra to get split view email on the plus, which is probably part of the reason.

Answer (score 3):

> If so then why iPhone 6 plus is differ from them ? Is it because it's screen is 0.8" bigger then iPhone 6 ? Does it matters ?

It matters when you are using a *split view controller*. When it has the same collapsed aspect on iPhone 5 and 6, it will split and show master and detail view controllers side by side in landscape orientation on iPhone 6+.

[image: Size class illustration]

It looks even more useless on iPad, since it has regular height and width size class on both portrait **and** landscape.

The point is, when you have *regular* size class, you should layout and show more content than on *compact* size class.

However size classes aren't related to the screen but to the view controller.

When you have your iPad with a master and a detail view controller, the master view controller has compact width/regular height, and the detail view controller has regular width/regular height.

You can still change child view controller's size classes by overriding them with

```
-(void)setOverrideTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)collection forChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController
```

and

```
-(UITraitCollection *)overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController.
```

It's a key concept for iPad since you can now on iOS9 have your app running in *compact* width with the new multi-task feature *(slide from the right of the screen)*.